# How to exclude a host when using APT mirror protocol

Tags: apt, software-sources

It is convenience to me to use `deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt` in my apt source file.
Now I need to have a way to block a single host in that list which I know is not reachable (or very slow) from my end.

The situation is: in my country (VN), there is a host that randomly blocks connection from some certain IPs. I asked its provider for checking but it isn't a nice process since I do not pay for any of their services.